# Constructive and destructive interference and their conditions

Tags: optics, interference

I came across different examples for constructive interference and I tried to figure out when the condition for constructive interference is $\Delta \phi = m\cdot\lambda$ and when it is $\Delta \phi = m\cdot\frac{\lambda}{2}$.
Maybe someone can explain or clarify this?

Comment: Consider two waves: $E=A cos (\omega t- kx)$ and $E=A cos (\omega t- kx +\Delta \phi)$. What the resulting field is clearly depends on $\Delta \phi$

Comment: What is $\Delta \phi$ in your formulas?